# Laravel WebSockets cannot send event

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher

I'm having troubles with dispatching events on my local Laravel configuration.

> I'm trying to dispach it directly from the dashboard http://localhost:8000/laravel-websockets, but it always return Error sending event. Even if it is connecting to the dashboard.

My config looks:

`.env` file:

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=local
PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=local
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
PUSHER_PORT=6001
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
PUSHER_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

Configuration in `boradcasting.php`:

```
 'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST', 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com') ?: 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com',
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
            ],
```

Configuration in `websockets.php`:

```
'apps' => [ [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],
```

I did enable all providers, and still not dispatching even from the dashboard.

I tried to create event and dispatch from the controller, but still not working.

Any ideas what could cause it?

Edit: just noticed in dashboard a message like:

> Channels current state is connected